# Should we disable in Mass Magento 2 modules

Tags: magento2

Following some recommendations from Andreas von Studnitz at 
https://www.integer-net.com/make-magento-2-small-again/, I have come up with a list of modules that I have successfully disabled on my development environment.

Many thanks Andreas. Now, the **composer.json** I put below shows a list of disabled modules that works for me. I came up with the list of **pros and cons** with disabling in mass Magento 2 modules.

So far, the pros are:

- use a codebase substantially lighter than the default Magento 2 codebase (recently, the latter has become very big)
- "composer update" runs faster, meaning, faster deployment on live
- easier to debug as there are less config, plugins in the system to debug
- less bugs if the disabled extension is not needed but yet does install attributes in the database (that was my case with Temando_Shipping module)
- less notifications in the backend, some unneeded *Modules updates notifications* do dissapear
- have smaller list of command-lines to remember
- have smaller list of indexes to run (recently google shopping was added regardless if we want to use the new Google default feature)

the cons may be:

- using a codebase that is not tested by the Magento team
- missing out on learning opportunities to use new developed features
- having a system that is different from most and therefore going through issues that might be unique to my environment

  ```
  {
     "name": "magento/project-enterprise-edition", 
     "require": {
          "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.3.3"
      },
      "replace": {
                  "temando/module-shipping-m2": "*",
                  "vertex/module-tax": "*",
                  "vertex/sdk": "*",
                  "magento/module-dhl": "*",
                  "magento/module-fedex": "*",
                  "magento/module-marketplace": "*",
                  "magento/module-multishipping": "*",
                  "magento/module-authorizenet": "*",
                  "magento/module-google-adwords": "*",
                  "magento/google-shopping-ads": "*",
                  "magento/module-sample-data": "*",
                  "magento/module-send-friend": "*",
                  "magento/module-swagger": "*",
                  "magento/module-swagger-webapi": "*",
                  "magento/module-swagger-webapi-async": "*",
                  "magento/module-ups": "*",
                  "magento/module-usps": "*",
                  "magento/module-braintree": "*",
                  "magento/module-signifyd": "*",
                  "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "*",
                  "magento/module-version": "*",
                  "yotpo/magento2-module-yotpo-reviews-bundle":"*",
                  "magento/module-worldpay":"*",        
                  "klarna/module-kp": "*",
                  "klarna/module-ordermanagement": "*",
                  "klarna/module-core": "*",
                  "magento/module-tax-graph-ql": "*",
                  "magento/module-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
                  "magento/module-weee-graph-ql": "*",
                  "magento/module-downloadable-graph-ql": "*",
                  "magento/module-analytics": "*",
                  "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "*",
                  "magento/module-customer-analytics": "*",
                  "magento/module-quote-analytics": "*",
                  "magento/module-review-analytics": "*",
                  "magento/module-sales-analytics": "*",
                  "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "*",

                  "magento/module-inventory": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-admin-ui": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-api": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product-admin-ui": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-cache": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-catalog": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-catalog-api": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-catalog-search": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-admin-ui": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-indexer": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-configuration": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-configuration-api": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-elasticsearch": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-admin-ui": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-indexer": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-import-export": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-indexer": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-admin-ui": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-api": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-multi-dimensional-indexer-api": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-product-alert": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-reservations": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-reservations-api": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-sales": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-sales-api": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-sales-frontend-ui": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-shipping": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-source-selection": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api": "*",
                  "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection": "*"
              }
  ```

  }

It is early for me to claim this way to use Magento is better but naively, it seems the pros do outweigh the cons? please do add your feedback to enrich our experience with Magento

Comment: My main worry about disabling a lot of code is that it adds an extra complexity when troubleshooting problems and upgrading. Perhaps more useful when a shop is live and stable.